# Encoding special characters from the text of a csv file

Tags: php, csv, explode

Need help with a csv file with special characters.

An example of what im working with:

```
122120061;11;Caleb;Unicombe;;GB; 
130658233;8;Th˙c;NgÙ C·t;;VN;
```

Each record is on a new line, however where I am runnign into issues is when splitting the records into arrays.

I am using

```
$player = explode(';', $data[$i]);
```

However when the player gets split, it comes back as

```
Array ( [0] => 130658233
        [1] => 8
        [2] => Th˙
        [3] => c
        [4] => NgÙ C·t
        [5] => 
        [6] => VN)
```

For some reason, with certain characters, it seems to use it as a spacer, which I don't want it to do.

I want it to return like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 130658233
        [1] => 8
        [2] => Th˙c
        [3] => NgÙ C·t
        [4] => 
        [5] => VN)
```

Any idea's?

Comment: what happens if you try [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)?

Comment: What's the character encoding of the cvs file?

Comment: Im using a form that will allow users to copy and paste the text of their csv, its not an actual file. So the question itself is a bit wrong.

The text is copied from a CSV file into a text box then submitted.

Comment: you should make sure you're working with utf-8. (php header, html charset, file encoding)

Comment: The CSV comes from a game, and what encoding they have used, I am not so sure. It is a multi national game, the CSV uses quite a few different special characters. All I know is that Russian, and Greek letters don't work with the SV as they come out as ???????